Цикл for с двумя переменными в Python
Проблема заключается в том, что по мере выполнения цикла значение i не увеличивается и, соответственно, в каждой строчке выводится только первая ячейка elements под индексом i = 0.
data = data_extract("source")
elements = data_extract("source")

for element in elements:
    i = 0
    print(elements.columns[i], data.loc[0, element])
    i = i + 1

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как следует изменить цикл, чтобы значение переменной i увеличивалось с каждым выполнением кода цикла!

Надо подумать о том, как решить эту задачу исключительно методами pandas, без применения цикла.

@AlexeyTrukhanov Для этого нужно понять, что тут вообще происходит )

@CrazyElf мне кажется берутся названия колонок одного датафрейма и печатаются пары <название колонки> <значение первой строки второго датафрейма в колонке с аналогичным названием>. Для меня остался открытым только один вопрос - может ли быть data_extract() генератором и, соответственно, могут ли elements и data отличаться. В любом случае написал свой ответ.

Поставить обнуление i ДО цикла
i = 0
for element in elements:
    print(elements.columns[i], data.loc[0, element])
    i = i + 1


Можно использовать стандартную функцию enumerate, которая создана как раз для таких случаев, когда нужна переменная с индексом текущего элемента:
for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    print(elements.columns[i], data.loc[0, element])


Не мог не попробовать решить только методами pandas, без for и без i.
elements.columns.map(lambda x: print(x, data.loc[0, x]))

